# validation for dropdown list within HTML

Tags: php, html

I have issues regarding to my drop-down list in my code and would like to know how I can ensure users chose an option before they can submit their queries.

This is the code im currently working on:

```
 <select required="required" name="type" class="dropdown">
     <option value="0">employee</option>
     <option value="1">Agency</option>
     <option value="2">Week</option>
 </select>
```

When I run the program, "select required" does not validate and make sure the user picks an option.

Comment: it is because you dont have empty value option. check out my post and try it.

Comment: Kindly upvote the answer

Comment: You had few syntax errors, I edited your code, it might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try this

<form action="sub.php">
<select class="dropdown" required>
<option value="">Select</option>
 <option value="1">Agency</option>
 <option value="2">Week</option>
 </select>
 <input type="submit"/>
 </form>
```

Comment: I just tried it and it does not work, is there any other way a user has to choose an option?

Comment: its works for me. try it exactly has I sent you perhaps in a separate file

Comment: Please what is the reason for the down vote??? I thought sharjeel is ok with the answer